# How import something from index.js in the same directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I have the similar folder structure as shown below

```
/components/organisms
-- ModuleA.vue
-- ModuleB.vue
-- index.js
```

content of `index.js`

```
export { default as ModuleA } from "./ModuleA.vue"
export { default as ModuleB } from "./ModuleB.vue"
```

If I try to import ModuleB into ModuleA, it generates an error

`ModuleA.vue` content

```
<script>
import { ModuleZ } from '@/components/molecules' // component from another directory, it works perfectly
import { ModuleB } from '@/components/organisms' // can't find, error
</script>
```

Comment: try `export * from "./ModuleA.vue"`

Comment: @joyBlanks, does not work :(

Comment: I figured out one thing, if the component I'm importing is after index.js, it works, if it's before, get a error, just not the reason or how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have an cyclic dependency structure with imports.

- ModuleA requires index
- index requires ModuleA

This generates undefined behaviour when bundled with webpack, usually manifesting as 1 of the files becoming undefined

Comment: What would you recommend me to do in this situation then?

Comment: Instead of `import { ModuleB } from '@/components/organisms` do `import ModuleB from '@/components/organisms/ModuleB `